# pandas series同士の結合について

Tags: python, python3, pandas

こんにちは。
series同士の結合について質問があります。
表Aと表Bの結合を行おうと、pd.concat([A,B])とすると、
表Cのように、行追加の形で行われてしまいます。
列結合を行うにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか？
（日付、みかん、りんごのように並ぶイメージです。）

ネットで見ると、恐らく表A、表Bの価格にカラム名がついていないから、
同一カラムと見なされ、下に追加される形になると思うのですが、
series型でのカラム名のつけ方がいまいちわかりません。。。。

```
表A
日付　
4/1 100
4/2 200
4/3 300

表B
4/1 200
4/3 500

表C
4/1 100
4/2 200
4/3 300
4/1 200
4/3 500
```

Comment: `concat()` の `axis` オプションを使うとできるのではないかと思います。こちら https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062135/combining-two-series-into-a-dataframe-in-pandas 等がご参考になるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: サンプルを実行可能な Python コードとして提示されると、より具体的な回答がもらえやすくなると思います。

Comment: 皆様ご丁寧なご回答ありがとうございます。なかなか返信出来ておらずどんどん回答が返ってきていたので、大変申し訳ないです。。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 列結合を行うにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか？

pandas.concat() のパラメータに `axis=1` を指定してください。
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

> ネットで見ると、恐らく表A、表Bの価格にカラム名がついていないから、同一カラムを見なされ、下に追加される形になると思うのですが、

同名のSeries同志でも列方向の結合はできます。

> series型でのカラム名のつけ方がいまいちわかりません。。。。

`Series.rename()` をご使用ください。
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html

```
import pandas as pd

ser1 = pd.Series([100,200,300],index=['4/1','4/2','4/3'])
ser2 = pd.Series([200,500],index=['4/1','4/3'])

pd.concat((ser1.rename('みかん'), ser2.rename('りんご')),axis=1,sort=False)
#     みかん  りんご
#4/1  100     200.0
#4/2  200       NaN
#4/3  300     500.0
```

Comment: やりたいことずばりこれでした。ご回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame({'日付': s1, 'みかん': s2, 'りんご': s3})
```

のように、 DataFrame を普通に新規に作成することが、質問者様のやりたいことだと思っていますが、いかがでしょうか？

Comment: そういう指定の方法もあるのですね。参考になりました。

Comment: import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series(['2016/10/1','2016/10/2','2016/10/3'])
s2 = pd.Series([100,200,300])
s3 = pd.Series([200,500])

df = pd.DataFrame({'日付': s1, 'みかん': s2, 'りんご': s3})

print(df)

Comment: 日付  みかん    りんご
0  2016/10/1  100  200.0
1  2016/10/2  200  500.0
2  2016/10/3  300    NaN

Comment: ただ、indexが日付にならず。。。

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'みかん': s2, 'りんご': s3},index=s1)とすると,日付がindexにはなるのですが、みかん、りんごの列がNaNになってしまいます。。。

Answer (score 0):

**やり直し回答**

`concat` だと @magichan さんの方式ですが、
他には単純に DataFrame を作って配列として代入するやり方があるようです。
[python pandasでの列（column）へのSeriesの追加](https://qiita.com/mu-777/items/e5c193af6b026a8b8ec5)
これだとカラム名を付けなくても出来ます。Series作成は@magichanさん回答からコピー

```
import pandas as pd

ser1 = pd.Series([100,200,300],index=['4/1','4/2','4/3'])
ser2 = pd.Series([200,500],index=['4/1','4/3'])

df = pd.DataFrame()
df[1] = ser1
df[2] = ser2
print(df)
```

結果はこうなります。

```
       1      2
4/1  100  200.0
4/2  200    NaN
4/3  300  500.0
```

**注**  
ただし、最初に代入するデータは、インデックスが文字列(数値でない?)の場合、全部のインデックスに対応するデータが揃っている必要があるようです。例えば 表B に '4/4' 200 といった 表A に無いデータがある場合は追加されません。

---

**質問を誤解してました：以下はDataFrame同士の処理です**

やりたいことは `concat` ではなく、`merge` ではないでしょうか？

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['4/1',100],['4/2',200],['4/3',300]], columns=(['日付','みかん']))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['4/1',200],['4/3',500]], columns=(['日付','りんご']))
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='日付', how='outer')
df3.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df3 = df3.astype({'みかん':int, 'りんご':int})
print(df3)
```

とすると、結果が以下になります。こんな形が欲しいのでは？

```
    日付  みかん  りんご
0  4/1  100  200
1  4/2  200    0
2  4/3  300  500
```

---

ちなみに `merge` の行を `concat` に変えると以下になります。

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

結果はこうなります。

```
    日付  みかん   日付  りんご
0  4/1  100  4/1  200
1  4/2  200  4/3  500
2  4/3  300    0    0
```

Comment: dataframeを作って、それの１列目はりんごの表、２列目はみかんの表というやりかたもあるのですね。参考になりました。